# Sum data in excel only when all fields are filled

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel spreadsheet with folowing:

Field A is manually entered and in B field I subtract 2,7% from field A. I extended that formula to all all B fields but its showing negative value as nothing is entered in all A fields.

see screenshot:

[image]

I want only to have visible data in field B when data is entered into A field.

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Should be a pretty easy fix, use this formula and copy down: `=IF(A1="","",*formula*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1-0.027*A1)
```

and copy down